# Finding the right size of array in LLVM IR

Tags: arrays, pointers, clang, llvm

I need to calculate the size (in bytes) of an array in GetElementPtr instruction `I`. I have previously been doing using the following logic to derive:

```
/* Get the bitWidth of the item */
int bitWidth = cast<IntegerType>(I->getOperand(2)->getType())->getBitWidth();

/* Find total number of elements in array */
Type *T = cast<PointerType>(cast<GetElementPtrInst>(I)->getPointerOperandType())->getElementType();
int no_of_elements = cast<ArrayType>(T)->getNumElements();

/* Compute total and return bytes */
return (no_of_elements * bitWidth) / 8
```

But there are tricky cases like the following where it breaks. Answer is **1024** bytes but my above logic will give **2048** as it is completely unaware of `i32`

```
%arrayidx932 = getelementptr inbounds [256 x i32], [256 x i32]* @array5, i64 0, i64 %idxprom931, !dbg !168
```

Anyone can help me correct my logic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `I->getOperand(2)`, you're getting one of the indices, which has nothing to do with the array type. If your code works in any case it's only by coincidence.

You've gotten `T` which in this case represents `[256 x i32]`. You've gotten the `256` using `getNumElements()`, and you can use `getElementType()` to get the `i32`, then figure out the size from there.

Probably a better way is to [get the `DataLayout` off your `Module`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#ae9bf71ba08ff29e1cd3ab0f9f3f0d07d), and then call [`getTypeAllocSize(T)`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1DataLayout.html#a1d6fcc02e91ba24510aba42660c90e29).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it. Can you help me in cases like this where I have array of arrays and want to compute the total size - getelementptr inbounds [8 x [256 x i64]], [8 x [256 x i64]]* @sample_array, i64 0, i64 5, i64 %and141

Comment: @PremAnand Using the methods on `DataLayout` should work in that case.